# Apex Managed Sharing using visual flow

Tags: apex-managed-sharing, visual-flows

I was trying to implement a custom record sharing logic and so I wrote a trigger to achieve it. Now I just came across a blog where it is written that this can be avoided by using a visual flow and process builder. I tried to go through the steps mentioned there which included creating variables on the flow (one for holding the id of the record to be shared, other for the id with whom the record is to shared) , then creating a record on `CustomObject__share` and then calling the flow through process builder.

The problem I'm facing here is on my 'Create a record' palette I couldn't find the share object of the one i wanted to share i.e the one with `__share`.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the OWD of that object ?

Comment: Got it Mohit,my bad. It wasn't Private so I couldn't see the share instance.

Comment: I am adding as answer so it helps others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The __share object is available only if your OWD for the object is set either "private" or "public read only" and it is not a detail object in master detail relationship .